# Run python command when a button is clicked

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a local webpage that lets people connected to my Wi-Fi interact with some stuff through the Raspberry Pi. For example, when they go to localhost/page.html and click a button, a song starts playing, or a light bulb turns on, or the music volume gets higher, or the system shuts down etc.

I managed to do this before, but it seemed too complicated and I presume there's another way. The way I did it: most of the buttons were used to turn ON or OFF something, so let's say it's a button that turns music on/off: I assigned a value to that button and then used PHP to increase its value with +1 whenever the button is clicked. Then I used beautifoulsoup (*the web scraping tool*) to get the value from the webpage and see if it's odd or even and with the python OS library I turned on the music depending on it.

So, to rephrase: how can I run a python command when someone clicks a button in a webpage, **without** using PHP ? I read about python web frameworks, but most of them seem more focused on complicated stuff that I don't need.

thank you.

LA: apparently some people think the question is unclear and put it '*on hold*'. I'll just copy what I wrote 5 rows above, which seemed pretty clear to me:

"How can I run a python script when someone clicks a button on a webpage."

Comment: Why don't you just use `exec` in your PHP script to start your python script directly?

Comment: I tried, but just a few commands worked when using 'exec', I don't know why (maybe for not giving permissions to execute them or something). I will do some research about it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Apache or some other web server on your RPI, then run your Python script as a CGI script.

I.e. When you call some url (e.g. http://localhost/cgi-bin/mypython.py) the web server runs this script and returns the stdout (everything printed) to your web browser.

Example of very simple script would be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

print "<html><head><title>Hello world!</title></head>"
print "<body>This is a Python CGI hello world example</body></html>"
```

If you enable CGI scripts in your web server settings and put this script into web server's CGI directory, you will be able to call it from web browser.

Web browser will receive the HTTP headers (Content-type...) and HTML that is printed out.

When you want your script to be able to receive arguments through HTTP GET or POST methods, use cgi module:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import cgi
# Uncomment the following to be able to see traceback in your browser
# if there is any:
#import cgitb
#cgitb.enable() # When you are done debugging, comment this back

# Get input from query string or POST method:
i = cgi.InputStorage()
# Mandatory HTTP header:
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
# ** At end of headers must be two \n. One is in there, another is added by print statement
# Web site contents:
print "<html><head><title>Hello world!</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "This is a Python CGI hello world example<br>"
follow = '<a href="http://localhost/cgi-bin/this_script.py?something=blah+blah+blah">Click here to see how something happens!</a>'
if i.has_key("something"):
    follow  = "<b>Something happened!</b><br>"
    follow += "The arg 'something' has value: "+i["something"].value
print follow
print "</body></html>"
```

If you want matters to be very simple, then serve index.html with all your buttons, links or whatever, and have them call different CGI script per each.

Script can then present back the index.html page when it is done with its action:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Do some work...
# And then:
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
f = open("/var/www/index.html", "rb")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

This is just one way to do it without any framework like Django, Flask etc.

Another would be to do the similar thing, which is more modern, and this is to use the server's Python module.

There is such a module for Apache and some other web servers.

When you are doing it this way, then Python interpreter is running inside the web server, and your script isn't started as a new process each time someone calls the URL.

Everything is much like PHP.

Writing such a script is similar to writing the CGI script.

There is third way.

You can write your own HTTP server in Python that will act upon URL's it receives.

For this, you may use already written SimpleHTTPServer from Python's standard library.

Just import it, subclass it, and make it react to different urls differently.

Answer (score 3):

Websites are divided into two sections, front-end and back-end. Front-end manages how the website looks like, while the back-end manages how the website acts like.

You cannot create a static website that can do any kind of behind-the-scenes processing without using a back-end language, or using an API of some kind that you can access using AJAX.

You *have to* use some back-end programming language/framework to be able to run *anything* in the background. PHP works, Python works, NodeJS, Ruby, anything that can act as a back-end framework works.

Using any of those languages/frameworks it should be quite easy to run scripts in the background.

A simple example would be using PHP to create a web-page that acts on a POST request and runs a Python script accordingly. You can use a database (MySQL is a nice example) or you can code the Python script itself so that it checks the status of whatever you're triggering somehow. Both should work.

As Johann Bauer mentioned in the comment, in PHP's case, instead of using a Python web scraper you should be able to run [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run the Python command.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I was trying to avoid installing PHP, Apache, MySQL for portability. I thought it was an easier way using just what Linux gives by default.